# How do I make the discord api await message for A or B?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my code to get user input, and there are two options the code has to check, but the code only registers the first option.

I've tried different syntaxes like `(content=('m!mode computer' or 'm!mode player'))` and none of them work.

```
 async def AgainstWho():
    global mode
    await client.send_message(message.channel, content='Play against the computer or another player?\n')
    mode = await client.wait_for_message(content=('m!mode computer' or 'm!mode player'))
    if mode == 'm!mode computer':
      mode = 1
    if mode == 'm!mode player':
      mode = 2
```

If the user types in `m!mode player` the code doesn't do anything but `m!mode computer` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'm!mode computer' or 'm!mode player'
'm!mode computer'
```

This is why. I'm assuming this is discord.py, [according to the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) what you want is this:

```
mode = await client.wait_for_message(check=lambda m: return m.content.startswith('m!mode'))
```

or the like.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `'m!mode computer' or 'm!mode player'` ; `or` will just return the first string with `True` as its boolean value, that is, any non-empty string ; so it will defaults to the first one (here `'m!mode computer'`).

You need to check that the content startswith `'m!mode '` and that the following "word" exactly match any of your options:

```py
 async def AgainstWho():
    global mode
    await client.send_message(message.channel, content='Play against the computer or another player?\n')
    mode = await client.wait_for_message(check=lambda m: return m.content.startswith('m!mode ') and m.content.split(' ')[1] in ('player', 'computer'))
    if mode == 'm!mode computer':
      mode = 1
    if mode == 'm!mode player':
      mode = 2
```

This only checks the first two "words" of the command. 'm!mode player' will work ; but so will 'm!mode player anything else behind'. If you want to avoid this behaviour and lower it to strict commands calls ; you may also check that `len(m.content.split(' ')) == 2`.

Also, avoid using `global`. Pass the variable as an argument to the function or make it a method of an object with the variable as an attribute.